# jQuery / CSS - setInterval initial state issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a little slide-show box thing that has an animated timer bar that resets each time the slide changes - you can see it working here: https://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/JJzZqK

My issue is that the initial state of the first slide has its opacity set to 0, but I would like it to be visible from the start. I've tried setting the css just for that slide to opacity:1, but then it remains visible throughout the entire cycle for some reason.

I also tried to adjust the start of the loop, but it cuts out the previous slide entirely then.

I'm going to post just the javascript here because (I know it's spaghetti, I suck), but it may be easier to understand if you look at it in action on the codepen.

How can I make the initial opacity of the first slide 1 without it remaining throughout the loop?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function() { 
  $('.sb-1-bot > div:first')
    .removeClass('sb-active')
    .next()
    .addClass('sb-active')
    .end()
    .appendTo('.sb-1-bot');

var all = $('.sb-1-icon svg');
var query1 = $('.sb-pg-1').css('opacity');
var icon1 = $('.sb-ic-1 svg');
var query2 = $('.sb-pg-2').css('opacity');
var icon2 = $('.sb-ic-2 svg');
var query3 = $('.sb-pg-3').css('opacity');
var icon3 = $('.sb-ic-3 svg');
var query4 = $('.sb-pg-4').css('opacity');
var icon4 = $('.sb-ic-4 svg');
var query5 = $('.sb-pg-5').css('opacity');
var icon5 = $('.sb-ic-5 svg');
if(query1 == 1) {
  all.css('opacity','0');
  icon1.css('opacity','1');
}
if(query2 == 1) {
  all.css('opacity','0');
  icon2.css('opacity','1');
}
if(query3 == 1) {
  all.css('opacity','0');
  icon3.css('opacity','1');
}
if(query4 == 1) {
  all.css('opacity','0');
  icon4.css('opacity','1');
}
if(query5 == 1) {
  all.css('opacity','0');
  icon5.css('opacity','1');
}


        var bar = $('.sb-pg-timer');
        var origin = 0;
                  bar.animate({
                    'width': origin,
            }, 0,function(){
        $(this).animate({
                'width' : '100%',
            }, 10000, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    'width': origin,
            }, 0)
                    })});

},  10000);

});
```

Comment: As for me the first slide is visible from the start. Chromium 59.0.3071.109-0ubuntu0.16.04.1291

Comment: The elements you are testing for opacity are different than the ones you are setting.

Comment: @qiAlex I believe he's on about the text not the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set the opacity as the default state but you want to set the `sb-active` class as the default class for `sb-pg-1` div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".sb-pg-1").addClass("sb-active");

  setInterval(function() {
    $(".sb-1-bot > div:first")
      .removeClass("sb-active")
      .next()
      .addClass("sb-active")
      .end()
      .appendTo(".sb-1-bot");

    var all = $(".sb-1-icon svg");
    var query1 = $(".sb-pg-1").css("opacity");
    var icon1 = $(".sb-ic-1 svg");
    var query2 = $(".sb-pg-2").css("opacity");
    var icon2 = $(".sb-ic-2 svg");
    var query3 = $(".sb-pg-3").css("opacity");
    var icon3 = $(".sb-ic-3 svg");
    var query4 = $(".sb-pg-4").css("opacity");
    var icon4 = $(".sb-ic-4 svg");
    var query5 = $(".sb-pg-5").css("opacity");
    var icon5 = $(".sb-ic-5 svg");
    if (query1 == 1) {
      all.css("opacity", "0");
      icon1.css("opacity", "1");
    }
    if (query2 == 1) {
      all.css("opacity", "0");
      icon2.css("opacity", "1");
    }
    if (query3 == 1) {
      all.css("opacity", "0");
      icon3.css("opacity", "1");
    }
    if (query4 == 1) {
      all.css("opacity", "0");
      icon4.css("opacity", "1");
    }
    if (query5 == 1) {
      all.css("opacity", "0");
      icon5.css("opacity", "1");
    }

    var bar = $(".sb-pg-timer");
    var origin = 0;
    bar.animate(
      {
        width: origin
      },
      0,
      function() {
        $(this).animate(
          {
            width: "100%"
          },
          3000,
          function() {
            $(this).animate(
              {
                width: origin
              },
              0
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }, 3000);
  
});
```

```css
/*deleteme*/
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;color:#333;foont-size:12px;margin:0;padding:0;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;font-weight:300;letter-spacing:1px;color:#222;}
p {font-style:italic;}
/*deleteme*/

.sb-1-icon svg {
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
}
.sb-1 {margin:0;padding:0;}
.sb-1-top {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
}
.sb-1-icon {
  background:#fff;
  padding:14px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px #ddd solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:auto;
}
.sb-1-icon svg {opacity:0;}
.sb-ic-1 svg {opacity:1;}
.sb-1-line-2 {
  position:absolute;
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  top:68px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.divider {
 position: relative;
 height: 1px;
}
.div-transparent:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 width: 90%;
 height: 1px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #ddd, transparent);
}

.sb-1-bot {
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
.sb-page {
  position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;opacity:0;}

.sb-active {opacity:1;}

.sb-pg-timer {
  width:0%;
  height:3px;
  float:left;
  background:#f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sb-1">
  <div class="sb-1-top">
    <div class="sb-1-line-2">
    <div class="divider div-transparent"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="sb-1-icon sb-ic-1">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<circle style="fill:#C9C9C9;" cx="253.04" cy="50.24" r="50.24"/>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M250.72,217.2L202.16,112c0,0-50.88,0.64-50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S251.04,217.2,250.72,217.2z"
  />
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M255.44,217.2L304,112c0,0,50.88,0.64,50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S255.12,217.2,255.44,217.2z"/>
</g>
<polygon style="fill:#FF5F5F;" points="253.04,112 218.08,112 253.04,189.36 288,112 "/>
<circle style="fill:#C9C9C9;" cx="407.04" cy="345.04" r="50.24"/>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M404.64,512l-48.56-105.2c0,0-50.88,0.64-50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S404.96,512,404.64,512z"/>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M409.36,512l48.56-105.2c0,0,50.88,0.64,50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S409.04,512,409.36,512z"/>
</g>
<polygon style="fill:#FF5F5F;" points="407.04,406.8 372.08,406.8 407.04,484.16 442,406.8 "/>
<circle style="fill:#C9C9C9;" cx="104.96" cy="345.04" r="50.24"/>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M102.64,512L54.08,406.8c0,0-50.88,0.64-50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S102.96,512,102.64,512z"/>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M107.36,512l48.56-105.2c0,0,50.88,0.64,50.88,47.52s0,57.68,0,57.68S107.04,512,107.36,512z"/>
</g>
<polygon style="fill:#FF5F5F;" points="104.96,406.8 70,406.8 104.96,484.16 139.92,406.8 "/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-1-icon sb-ic-2">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <rect x="251.28" y="28.4" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
 <path style="fill:#C9C9C9;" d="M260.72,455.28h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V455.28z M260.72,417.28h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V417.28z M260.72,379.36
  h-9.44V360.4h9.44V379.36z M260.72,341.44h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V341.44z M260.72,303.44h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V303.44z M260.72,265.52
  h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V265.52z M260.72,227.6h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V227.6z M260.72,189.6h-9.44v-18.96h9.44V189.6z M260.72,151.68h-9.44
  v-18.96h9.44V151.68z M260.72,113.76h-9.44V94.8h9.44V113.76z M260.72,75.76h-9.44V56.8h9.44V75.76z"/>
 <rect x="251.28" y="474.24" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
 <rect x="452.96" y="130.56" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
 <path style="fill:#C9C9C9;" d="M462.48,335.28h-9.44v-19.52h9.44V335.28z M462.48,296.24h-9.44v-19.52h9.44V296.24z M462.48,257.2
  h-9.44v-19.52h9.44V257.2z M462.48,218.16h-9.44v-19.52h9.44V218.16z M462.48,179.04h-9.44v-19.52h9.44V179.04z"/>
 <rect x="452.96" y="354.88" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
 <path style="fill:#C9C9C9;" d="M256,262.96l-8.72-5.28l4.88-8.08l3.84,2.32l7.44-4.48l4.88,8.08L256,262.96z M231.04,247.92
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L231.04,247.92z M284.56,245.68l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L284.56,245.68z M198.72,228.32
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L198.72,228.32z M316.96,226.16l-4.96-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L316.96,226.16z M166.32,208.8
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L166.32,208.8z M349.28,206.64l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L349.28,206.64z M133.92,189.28
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L133.92,189.28z M381.68,187.04l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L381.68,187.04z M101.52,169.68
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L101.52,169.68z M414.08,167.52l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L414.08,167.52z M69.2,150.16
  l-16.16-9.76l2-3.36l-2.96-5.52l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32l-9.36,4.96L74,142.08L69.2,150.16z M446.4,148l-4.88-8.08l13.76-8.32l0.72,1.2
  l1.44-2.64l9.92,5.28L446.4,148z M436.24,129.6l-16.72-8.88l4.48-8.32l16.72,8.88L436.24,129.6z M89.92,122.08l-4.4-8.32
  l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L89.92,122.08z M402.88,111.84l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L402.88,111.84z M123.28,104.32l-4.4-8.32
  l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L123.28,104.32z M369.44,94.16l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L369.44,94.16z M156.72,86.64l-4.4-8.32
  l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L156.72,86.64z M336,76.4l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L336,76.4z M190.16,68.88l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88
  l4.4,8.32L190.16,68.88z M302.64,58.64l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L302.64,58.64z M223.52,51.12l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88
  l4.4,8.32L223.52,51.12z M269.2,40.96l-15.44-8.16l1.44-2.64l-2.64-5.04L256,23.2l17.68,9.36L269.2,40.96z"/>
 <path style="fill:#C9C9C9;" d="M256,491.76l-8.72-5.28l4.88-8.08l3.84,2.32l7.44-4.48l4.88,8.08L256,491.76z M231.04,476.72
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L231.04,476.72z M284.56,474.56l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L284.56,474.56z M198.72,457.2
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L198.72,457.2z M316.88,454.96l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L316.88,454.96z M166.32,437.6
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L166.32,437.6z M349.28,435.44l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L349.28,435.44z M133.92,418.08
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08L138.8,410L133.92,418.08z M381.68,415.92l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L381.68,415.92z M101.52,398.56
  l-16.16-9.76l4.88-8.08l16.16,9.76L101.52,398.56z M414.08,396.4l-4.88-8.08l16.16-9.76l4.88,8.08L414.08,396.4z M69.12,378.96
  l-16.16-9.76l2-3.36L52,360.32l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32l-9.36,4.96l10.16,6.16L69.12,378.96z M446.4,376.8l-4.88-8.08l13.76-8.32
  l0.72,1.2l1.44-2.64l9.92,5.28L446.4,376.8z M436.24,358.48l-16.72-8.88l4.48-8.4l16.72,8.88L436.24,358.48z M89.92,350.96
  l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L89.92,350.96z M402.88,340.72l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L402.88,340.72z M123.28,333.2
  l-4.4-8.32L135.6,316l4.4,8.32L123.28,333.2z M369.44,322.96l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L369.44,322.96z M156.72,315.44
  l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L156.72,315.44z M336.08,305.28l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.4l16.72,8.88L336.08,305.28z M190.16,297.76
  l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L190.16,297.76z M302.64,287.52l-16.72-8.88l4.4-8.32l16.72,8.88L302.64,287.52z M223.52,280
  l-4.4-8.32l16.72-8.88l4.4,8.32L223.52,280z M269.2,269.76l-15.44-8.16l1.44-2.64l-2.64-5.04l3.44-1.84l17.68,9.36L269.2,269.76z"
  />
</g>
<g>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="457.76" cy="131.04" r="25.76"/>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="457.76" cy="364.48" r="25.76"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect x="49.52" y="130.56" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
 <path style="fill:#C9C9C9;" d="M59.04,335.28h-9.52v-19.52h9.44v19.52H59.04z M59.04,296.24h-9.52v-19.52h9.44v19.52H59.04z
   M59.04,257.2h-9.52v-19.52h9.44v19.52H59.04z M59.04,218.16h-9.52v-19.52h9.44v19.52H59.04z M59.04,179.04h-9.52v-19.52h9.44
  v19.52H59.04z"/>
 <rect x="49.52" y="354.88" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="9.44" height="9.44"/>
</g>
<g>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="54.24" cy="131.04" r="25.76"/>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="54.24" cy="364.48" r="25.76"/>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="256" cy="256" r="25.76"/>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="256" cy="25.76" r="25.76"/>
 <circle style="fill:#FF5F5F;" cx="256" cy="486.24" r="25.76"/>
</g>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-1-icon sb-ic-3">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon style="fill:#002833;" points="389.68,502.08 261.36,393.52 132.96,502.08 112.32,477.68 261.36,351.6 410.32,477.68 "/>
<rect x="21.36" y="30.72" style="fill:#8AD5DD;" width="469.36" height="341.84"/>
<g>
 <rect y="9.92" style="fill:#002833;" width="512" height="21.36"/>
 <rect y="372.56" style="fill:#002833;" width="512" height="21.36"/>
 <rect x="165.36" y="452.56" style="fill:#002833;" width="192" height="10.64"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M99.12,164l9.92,38.24c2.16,8.4,4.16,16.16,5.6,23.92h0.48c1.68-7.6,4.16-15.68,6.64-23.76
  l12.32-38.4h11.52l11.68,37.6c2.8,9.04,4.96,16.96,6.72,24.56h0.48c1.2-7.6,3.28-15.52,5.76-24.4L180.96,164h13.52l-24.24,75.2
  h-12.4l-11.52-35.92c-2.64-8.4-4.8-15.84-6.72-24.72h-0.4c-1.84,9.04-4.16,16.8-6.8,24.88l-12.16,35.76h-12.4L85.12,164L99.12,164
  L99.12,164z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M215.36,164l9.92,38.24c2.16,8.4,4.16,16.16,5.6,23.92h0.48c1.68-7.6,4.16-15.68,6.64-23.76
  l12.32-38.4h11.52l11.68,37.6c2.8,9.04,4.96,16.96,6.72,24.56h0.48c1.2-7.6,3.28-15.52,5.76-24.4L297.2,164h13.52l-24.24,75.2
  h-12.4l-11.52-35.92c-2.64-8.4-4.8-15.84-6.72-24.72h-0.32c-1.84,9.04-4.16,16.8-6.8,24.88l-12.16,35.76h-12.4L201.44,164
  L215.36,164L215.36,164z"/>
 <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M331.6,164l9.92,38.24c2.16,8.4,4.16,16.16,5.6,23.92h0.48c1.68-7.6,4.16-15.68,6.64-23.76
  l12.32-38.4h11.52l11.68,37.6c2.8,9.04,4.96,16.96,6.72,24.56h0.48c1.2-7.6,3.28-15.52,5.76-24.4L413.44,164h13.52l-24.24,75.2
  h-12.4l-11.52-35.92c-2.64-8.4-4.8-15.84-6.72-24.72h-0.32c-1.84,9.04-4.16,16.8-6.8,24.88L352.8,239.2h-12.4L317.68,164L331.6,164
  L331.6,164z"/>
</g>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-1-icon sb-ic-4">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <polygon style="fill:#FF5F5F;" points="431.12,512 382.8,463.68 448.8,397.68 498.16,447.04  "/>
 
  <rect x="341.617" y="351.998" transform="matrix(-0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 -0.7071 881.5287 386.2147)" style="fill:#FF5F5F;" width="38.32" height="47.36"/>
</g>
<g>
 
  <rect x="350.007" y="384.51" transform="matrix(-0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 -0.7071 968.1555 422.1568)" style="fill:#002833;" width="93.279" height="54.159"/>
 <circle style="fill:#002833;" cx="219.6" cy="205.76" r="205.76"/>
</g>
<circle style="fill:#EFEFEF;" cx="219.6" cy="205.76" r="184.24"/>
<rect x="140.88" y="201.28" style="fill:#FF5F5F;" width="26.24" height="71.76"/>
<g>
 <rect x="97.2" y="230.56" style="fill:#8AD5DD;" width="26.24" height="42.4"/>
 <rect x="184.64" y="161.36" style="fill:#8AD5DD;" width="26.24" height="111.6"/>
</g>
<rect x="228.32" y="89.6" style="fill:#FF5F5F;" width="26.24" height="183.36"/>
<rect x="272.08" y="126.64" style="fill:#8AD5DD;" width="26.24" height="146.4"/>
<rect x="315.76" y="185.6" style="fill:#FF5F5F;" width="26.24" height="87.68"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-1-icon sb-ic-5">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#002833;" d="M0,355.28V31.36c0-5.76,4.72-10.48,10.48-10.48H501.6c5.68,0,10.4,4.72,10.4,10.48v323.92"/>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#E8E8E8;" d="M512,355.28v41.76c0,5.76-4.72,10.48-10.48,10.48H10.48C4.72,407.52,0,402.8,0,397.04v-41.76H512z"
  />
 <rect x="146.32" y="480.64" style="fill:#E8E8E8;" width="219.44" height="10.48"/>
</g>
<polygon style="fill:#C9C9C9;" points="329.12,480.64 182.88,480.64 193.28,407.52 318.72,407.52 "/>
<rect x="20.88" y="41.76" style="fill:#EFEFEF;" width="470.24" height="292.56"/>
<circle style="fill:#C9C9C9;" cx="167.28" cy="145.84" r="36.32"/>
<g>
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M165.6,266.64l-35.12-76.08c0,0-36.8,0.48-36.8,34.32s0,41.68,0,41.68S165.84,266.64,165.6,266.64z"
  />
 <path style="fill:#002833;" d="M169.04,266.64l35.12-76.08c0,0,36.8,0.48,36.8,34.32s0,41.68,0,41.68S168.72,266.64,169.04,266.64z
  "/>
</g>
<polygon style="fill:#FF5F5F;" points="167.28,190.56 142,190.56 167.28,246.48 192.56,190.56 "/>
<g>
 <rect x="282.48" y="135.84" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="135.6" height="10.48"/>
 <rect x="282.48" y="167.2" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="135.6" height="10.48"/>
 <rect x="282.48" y="198.56" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="135.6" height="10.48"/>
 <rect x="282.48" y="229.84" style="fill:#C9C9C9;" width="135.6" height="10.48"/>
</g>
</svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sb-1-bot">
    <div class="sb-page sb-pg-1">
      <h2>Dedicated Team</h2>
      <p>All of our editors are experienced SEO & content professionals. We build our strategy around your goals and function as an extension of your company.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-page sb-pg-2">
      <h2>Market Research</h2>
      <p>We learn about every facet of your industry and competitor strategies to make sure your brand can connect with your target markets first. We go the extra mile by taking advantage of new market opportunities.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-page sb-pg-3">
      <h2>Proven Strategy</h2>
      <p>We know what works and what doesn’t. By staying on top of Google’s algorithm updates and using time-tested methods, we can create interesting evergreen content with continuously growing traffic.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-page sb-pg-4">
      <h2>SEO</h2>
      <p>We go the extra mile by restructuring and optimizing your site. We also have extensive off-page resources to ensure your content ranks high.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sb-page sb-pg-5">
      <h2>Branding & Authority</h2>
      <p>We perform extensive research to ensure your content will be contributing to your field rather than just diluting it. Brand awareness will grow significantly, and your status as a trusted source will grow with it.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sb-pg-timer"></div>
</div>


<!---
    <div class="sb-1-line-2">
    <div class="divider div-transparent"></div>
      </div>
-->
```

Comment: I almost got it right before but I was trying to do that from within the setInterval - thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Keep it up! you're doing great :)

Comment: thanks! i've noticed that if you go to another window or tab whilst the code is going (on the codepen), the loop gets all messed up when you return to it. i'm just wondering if there's an event listener that i can use to reset the thing when someone switches windows...maybe that's silly though

Comment: @Joel how does it mess up? It seems like it's working fine for me when switching tabs/windows.

Comment: well specifically the little loading bar freezes up

Comment: @joel I see it! I think this might be another problem? Have you thought about replacing it with a pure css solution?

Comment: i was hoping to keep it in the jquery so the timing is synchronized - you can see i placed a var for time at the top now that both the bar and the slides use

Answer (score 1):

You are never changing the opacity on the text portion. You only change the class, adding and removing sb-active.

So, the opacity of the text is determined by the css. If you add opacity to the element, it will override the css.

Instead, add the sb-active class to the element initially.

EDIT:

working example: https://codepen.io/pen/MoRwpq

moved animateBar to a separate function to call initially.

```
function animateBar()
{
    var bar = $('.sb-pg-timer');
    var origin = 0;
                  bar.animate({
                    'width': origin,
            }, 0,function(){
    $(this).animate({
                'width' : '100%',
            }, 3000, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    'width': origin,
            }, 0)
                    })});

  }
```

Comment: this one is good too - you were able to get the bar to load up the first time around too